# Play framework 2.5.x/ Scala How to configure compression (GZIP) for all response for both Http and WS

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, compression, playframework-2.5

Is there a way to configure compression (GZIP) for all the response by doing changes only in application.conf?. What are the best ways to compress the response?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/GzipEncoding ?

Comment: Is this a question about Play 2.3 or Play 2.5? Your title says one thing and your tags say another.

Comment: Sorry about the tag I am using 2.5. I read the post that you have commanted. For WS we have a option like Shown below  "
play.ws.compressionEnabled = true" Is ther any option like that for Http?

Comment: Again, have you followed the docs? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/GzipEncoding

Comment: @Salem sorry about the delayed reply. Yes i have seen this link. My question was is there a way to just add some configuration in application.conf and get the Gzip working like how we do it in WS (
play.ws.compressionEnabled = true). Is there any ways that this can be done in Http as well?

Comment: @Prakash Unfortunately, I think it does not. You can always create two filter classes, one with the gzip filter and the other not, and then choose whatever you want to use in application.conf...

Comment: @Salem Ok thank you got my answer.